# For bazel c++ project, how to use "dlopen/sym" to locate my own output library?

Tags: c++, project, bazel, dlopen

My question is: how to specify/config so that my "dlopen" function can find the ".so" library file built out by my own bazel project?

I've got a very simple project like this:

```
ls
BUILD  WORKSPACE  hello-dl.cc  hello-greet.cc  hello-greet.h

cat hello-greet.cc
#include<stdio.h>
void f(){
    printf("f function\n");
}

cat hello-dl.cc
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main(){
    void * handle = dlopen("hello-greet", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    void (*f)() = (void (*)()) dlsym(handle, "f");
    char* error = dlerror();
    if (error != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    f();
    dlclose(handle);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}
```

and the "BUILD" file content is:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello-dl",
    srcs = ["hello-dl.cc"],
    linkopts = ['-ldl', '-lm']
)
cc_library(
    name = "hello-greet",
    srcs = ["hello-greet.cc"],
    hdrs = ["hello-greet.h"],
)
```

I built both the library and the binary:

```
bazel build //:hello-greet
bazel build //:hello-world
```

When run it, it says it cannot find the library file:

```
bazel run hello-dl
....
hello-greet: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How how to solve my problem?

Comment: The easiest way would be to add a DT_RUNPATH or DT_RPATH relative to the origin, e.g. `-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../lib` in `linkopts` (depending on where you put your executable and library files).

Comment: I tried "linkopts = ['-ldl', '-lm', '-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../lib']" but it failed, seems syntax error. How to fix it?

Comment: It looks like strings are subject to Make variable substitution, so you need to escape the $ character. $$ORIGIN should do it.

Comment: Thanks, after I change BUILD to have "-Wl,-rpath,bazel-bin", I can "bazel build hello-greet && bazel build hello-dl" and then "bazel-bin/hello-dl" to run it successfully